# Unresponsive USB on a Raspi Model A

Tags: usb, power

I've been running a headless Pi Model A (1 USB and no ethernet port) for a little while and it's just stopped working.  The wifi dongle shows no life, and the pluggin keyboard has no effect.  So I can't get networked to ssh or login plugged into the tv.  I've measured the USB voltage with a multimeter and it reads 4.2V.  Does this sound like a dead Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.2 volts is really below any USB specification, thus quite a bad sign. I assume that you measured the voltage of the power supply without the RPi is being ok? I also assume that you tried to remove all additional parts (being just the wifi dongle in this case) and measured the voltage again.

Before trying a new power supply I'd recommend to

1. check the open circuit voltage of the power supply
2. measure inrush current with the RPi
3. check voltage regulator (maybe something obvious is wrong, it's hot or so)

Also a good read: http://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/dead-raspberry-pi/dead-raspberry-pi.html

Answer (score 2):

That is not enough power, my investigations returned.

```
Volts   State
4.92    boot
4.89    ls -lR /
5.05    halt
```

Suggest you try a new power supply.

Note that with a good power supply but a bad cable i got

```
Volts   State
4.71    boot
4.66    ls -lR /
4.99    halt
```

Which was enough to cause random problems and general unstability.

Comment: Thanks rob, useful to have a tested idea of lower voltage limit